# is NUMBER <= FALSE?

Tags: php, if-statement

in a PHP if statement. is a number greater than or equal to false?

For example:

```
if(5743 <= FALSE) {
    echo 'it is true!';
}
else {
    echo 'it is false!';
}
```

What would be the output?

Comment: did you try it??

Comment: sorry to lazy and it was quicker to ask lol win for stackoverflow

Comment: well i got codepad.org out of it :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**FALSE**

see demo: http://codepad.org/QLDWMMG7

Comment: well i lost alot of reputation for asking this question but i got codepad.org out of it. cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

```
5743 <= FALSE
```

is equivalent to:

```
(bool)5743 <= FALSE
```

is equivalent to:

```
TRUE <= FALSE
```

is equivalent to:

```
FALSE
```

See the reference table from the manual [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).